# Is there WiX pre-defined variable for "C:\Users\Public" folder?

Tags: wix

I want to install some files to a folder located at "`C:\Users\Public\MyApp`". Is there a pre-defined variable in [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) that resolves to "C:\Users\Public" in Windows 7 and equivalent location in other versions of Windows?

Comment: -1 for not using common application data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved as below:

```
<Directory Id="UserPublicMyAppFolder" Name="MineSched">
</Directory>

<SetDirectory Id="UserPublicMyAppFolder" Value="C:\Users\Public\MyApp" />
```

Comment: Why would you hard code C:\Users\Public? What happens if the user's Windows locale is not English?

Comment: Good point. It wasn't my decision. I tried to convince PA that  [CommonAppDataFolder] is a better choice but decision is made by higher management. I will raise the concern. Thanks.

Comment: @ta.speot.is from experience, it would still work. At least on when the locale is Hebrew it works

Answer (score 2):

No. WiX defines only these variables in Setup projects:

```
sys.CURRENTDIR
sys.SOURCEFILEPATH
sys.SOURCEFILEDIR
sys.PLATFORM
```

And WiX variables are only used when the setup package is built.

You probably mean Windows Installer properties. They depend on the Windows Installer version are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties). Note: when reading the required version of Windows Installer, the docs do you the disservice of listing the minimum version that could actually be installed on a particular operating system version. The minimum version to support a property would be the lowest of those.

The answer is still "no." In fact, there isn't even a [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to locate that folder. As of Windows Vista, there is a [FOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, though Windows Installer doesn't use it.

The point is, *that's not where installed files go!* Please consider [CommonAppDataFolder].

Comment: Thanks Tom, I figured it out myself. And I agree with you that "C:\Users\Public\MyApp" is not where installed files should go. But I am not the one who makes the decision in the organisation.